# Save postgreSQL data point as python variable

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using postgreSQL and python together and wondering how I can save a selected postgreSQL data point (in this case a url), as a variable in Python?

```
import psycopg2
import sys


def insertRowInPostgreSQL():
    con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydb' user='bond'")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT url FROM urls LIMIT 1;")
    con.commit()
```

I tried some thing like `myVariable = cur.execute("SELECT url FROM urls LIMIT 1;")`, but that didn't work.

I've also been following [a tutorial](http://blog.lerner.co.il/turning-postgresql-rows-arrays-array/), which helpd me to create the following query, but I don't understand how what is creates in postgreSQL is then saved as a python array: `SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT url FROM urls LIMIT 1), ', ');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you  use `cur.fetchone()` [(see docs)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html):

```
def insertRowInPostgreSQL():
    con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='myDb' user='bond'")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT url FROM urls),',') AS required_urls;")
    allEmailUrls = cur.fetchone()
    allEmailUrls = allEmailUrls[0]
    allEmailUrls = [url.strip() for url in allEmailUrls.split(',')]
    for individualUrl in allEmailUrls:
        print individualUrl
    con.commit()

insertRowInPostgreSQL()
```